# android Black line above the bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I'm designing an app and in the bottom navigation bar area, the black line at the top won't go away no matter what I do. I've given up on rounding the borders because of this, is there any way to adjust it? Here is my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/navi_corner"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="#618264"
        app:itemTextColor="#618264"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_frame"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu_bottom"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,UnknownId"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@color/white"

        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavi"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

style.xml

```
    <style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/cafe_24</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

nav_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FAFCFA" />
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

[nav image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldxTI.png)

I want to remove the black line